# Hide the value of a hypothesis introduced by `pose`, show only its type

Tags: coq, coq-ssreflect

In proof mode, if I know an expression `e` of type `T`, I can write `pose foo : T := e` to add `foo := e : T` as a hypothesis. Often, I don't care about that `foo` is the same as `e`, I only care that `foo` has type `T`, so in the hypotheses list I would like to see `foo : T` instead of `foo := e : T` to reduce mental clutter. How can I do that?

Comment: I get syntax error at `:` if I use `pose foo : T := t1`. But `pose (foo := t1)` works here.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner I get no syntax error on the following example: `Lemma foo S T (f : S -> T) (s : S) : T. Proof. pose foo : T := f s.`

Comment: @CrabMan Which Coq version do you use? I get a syntax error on your example on all Coq versions I can test from 8.6 to 8.15.

Comment: @Zimmi48 Coq 8.13 and I don't know which version of mathcomp. Do `From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect ssrfun ssrbool eqtype ssrnat seq.` and then it'll work.

Comment: OK, then this explains why (that's the SSReflect pose tactic)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that

```
assert (foo := t1).
```

([docs here](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.assert)) does what you want?

Answer (score 2):

`assert` was already mentioned in another answer. An alternative (if you like the word `pose`) is [`pose proof`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacv.pose-proof). Several syntax variants are supported, including the one with `:=`. In practice, the two will produce exactly the same proof, so this is a purely stylistic choice.

Answer (score 1):

The question text did not make that clear, but it turns out (from the comments) that what you are using is actually the `pose` tactic from SSReflect (documentation [here](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ssreflect-proof-language.html#coq:tacn.pose-(ssreflect))) and not the standard Coq `pose` tactic (documentation [here](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.pose)). If you want to keep using SSReflect tactics, then the recommended answer to your question is to replace `pose` with `have` (documentation [here](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/ssreflect-proof-language.html#coq:tacn.have)) when you do not need the body. E.g.:

```
Require Import ssreflect.

Lemma foo S T (f : S -> T) (s : S) : T.
Proof.
have foo : T := f s.
```